# getting array indexoutofbound exception in maximo anywhere

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have a list view, i select one row and try to delete a record. However when i try to delete records from top to bottom order. Last item click throws array indexoutofbound exception. Please advise with any alternatives or is this known issue in Maximo Anywhere

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved when i removed selRecord.deleteLocal() method instead im setting a flag to know whether record is deleted or know since i need deleted record for another scenario